# On refresh, checked = true based on firebase value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, checkbox

I have an aplication connected to a firebase realtime. I can set data to the firebase with my checkbox, but im facing problems to set the atribute checked based on firebase data.

**MY JS CODE**

```
firebase.database().ref('0001/switches/001').on('value', snapshot => {

            var chValue = snapshot.val();

            console.log(chValue);

            if (chValue == true) {
                document.getElementById("sch1").checked = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("sch1").checked = false;
            }                
        });
```

I confirme that the chValue is working based on firebase data, using the console.log() but, I dont know why...

**THIS**

```
document.getElementById("sch1").checked = true;
```

Is not working! If i put outside the firebase function it works, I could find the reason.

**THIS WORK**

```
 firebase.database().ref('0001/switches/001').on('value', snapshot => {

            var chValue = snapshot.val();

            consolo.log(chValue);

            if (chValue == true) {
                document.getElementById("sch1").checked = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("sch1").checked = false;
            }            
        });

//Outside firebase function
        document.getElementById("sch1").checked = true;
```

Comment: When `console.log(chValue);` fires, what are the values? Using `==` rather than `===` for equality comparison can cause unexpected results.

Comment: Try logging the type of `chValue` like `console.log(chValue, typeof chValue)`. I believe you are receiving a string. And `true == "true"` is not `true`.

Comment: Ty for reply. Even I put just: document.getElementById("sch1").checked = true; inside the firebase function it dont work, but, if i put it outside works...

Comment: Return on console.log() http://prntscr.com/no3t9e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution like this:

```
 state = { swichStatus: undefined }

    switch1() {
        firebase.database().ref('0001/switches/001').set(1);
    }

    toggleSwitch = (value) => {

        this.setState({ swichStatus: value })

        if (value == true) {
            firebase.database().ref('0001/switches/001').set(true);
        }
        else {
            firebase.database().ref('0001/switches/001').set(false);
        }
    }
```